# Problemas al utilizar <select> en PHP

Tags: php

Hice un código para seleccionar un país y mostrar el que hayas seleccionado en el *select*, pero no sé porque no muestra los países que coloqué en la columna *flag (tipo: enum)* de la tabla *players*, el *select* me sale en blanco sólo mostrando lo que tengo seleccionado y sin mostrar los países para seleccionar. ¿Alguna ayuda de cómo solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public static function getAllowFlags(){
    $flaglist = [];

    $flag_q = Db::query('SELECT flag FROM players');
    while($l = $flag_q->fetch_assoc()) {
            $flaglist[] = $l;
    }

    return $flaglist;
}

$AllowFlags = Account::getAllowFlags();

<?php foreach($AllowFlags as $key => $flag) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?=$flag['flag'];?>" <?=$flag['flag']?'selected':'';?>><?=$flag['flag'];?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: si haces un select distinct sale igual?

Comment: Sí, no sé que hace falta en la consulta sql o en el código php.

Comment: entiendo que la primera imagen es el resultado html?

Comment: Así es, ¿alguna solución?

Comment: ahora mismo no puedo probarlo(estoy desde el telefono) pero si hay un for each  y un montón de líneas en blanco, yo diría que en la base de datos los datos son esos, es decir VE, NULL, NULL, ....CO.

Comment: por eso te digo lo del distinct.

Comment: En la columna "flag" solo añadí 2 países, VE y CO. Añadí el "distinct" y quito los null, pero por defecto en la columna "flag" es NULL.

Comment: tal vez se por que es tarde, pero me acabo de perder... tienes una tabla, players. De aquí tienes un campo enum null, VE y CO

Comment: de estos datos quieres que en el html se visualice únicamente ve y co

Comment: Sí, los datos que están en la columna "flag" se muestren en el <select> por <option>, como opciones normales.

Comment: si es así, con el.distinct ya te va bien. por que ? por que cuando tengas 50 registros y 30 sean co y 20 ve en el select se mostrarán asi 30 co y 20 ve y si hubiera algún null pues tambien

Answer (score 1):

Según lo aclarado en los comentarios y viendo la estructura la tabla, lo único que puedes hacer, para no cambiar la estructura de la tabla modificar tu query.

```
select distinct(flag) from players
```

de esta forma sólo tendrás los dos resultados que esperas.

Hay que decir que no es la mejor solucion, pues lo suyo sería hacer un tabla de países y relacionarla con este campo (foren key).
Saludos ;)

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar bien, se muestra de esta manera ahora con el distinct: 
https://imgur.com/oyzfvPf. ¿Entonces cuál sería el método más recomendable?

Comment: en tu tabla, exactamente que datos tienes?  y otra cosa, estas usando in framework o algo asi? p9r que no llegó a entender por que pones <?= en vez de <?php

Comment: Utilizo un framework que resume las variables, de <?php a <?=. Ya venía con el CMS por defecto. En mi tabla de *players* tengo los datos de los usuarios, y en la columna *flag* tipo ENUM tengo los países a elegir, por defecto sale NULL (es decir, sin ningún país elegido)

Comment: ok en tu tabla tienes datos con VE y CO? yo lo estoy haciendo, sin frameworks ni la ternaria en el option y me sale perfectamente.

Comment: prueba primero hacerlo sin la ternaria, y luego con. Es muy posible que sea tema de eso.